# Why is "going to " used in this case

Tags: future

> Next month I'm going to start working on a farm one day a week.

Why not present continuous "am starting" as next month is precised so we know that present continuous  indicates future and it is certain it is more than an intention.May be present simple could also fit

OA2_1a_gramma

Comment: Any of those three actually work.

Comment: Present continuous would also be correct in that sentence. We can't guess why the writer chose to use "be going to".